# counting records in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, countif

I'm querying data from SQL SERVER, and using a lot of CASE statement to get the appropriate results. After the data is queries, I dump it to excel. Here's what I'm trying to achieve...

Query looks something like...

```
Select ClientName, ClientNo, 
   Case when AAA=0 then 'N' Else 'Y' End As AAA,
   Case when BBB=0 then 'N' Else 'Y' End as BBB,
   Case when CCC=0 then 'N' Else 'Y' End as CCC
From tblClientInformation
```

So this is a much shortened version of the query, I actually have about 17 Case statements. Once I dump this data to Excel spreadsheet, I do a COUNTIF function to take a count of all Y values for each clientName/ClientNO, so the data looks something like...

```
ClientName    ClientNo     AAA        BBB       CCC       TotalY
Bob Smith     1775         Y          N         Y         2
```

So in TotalY I basically use CountIF function in excel to count all the Y values starting in AAA - ZZZ (example). However, since my query yields around 12000 records, it seems to be quite time consuming.

Is there any way that I can count the Y's in the query so that by the time my data is queried in SQL SERVER, all I have to do is simply dump it in excel, rather than adding on the Column TotalY with CountIF function?

Comment: what's the other value for the current case statement that you're setting to N and Y? Only 1 and 0 or can it be a range of numbers?

Comment: @scsimon there could be multiple values, but the end result will be either Y or N. In other words, there are values from 0 - 5, and I do more ELSE's before I derive at N or Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the data types for fields AAA, BBB, and CCC? If they're integers, what are the possible values? If it is of some numeric data type, and the only values are 0 and 1, you can do it without a CTE

```
Select 
    ClientName,
    ClientNo, 
    Case when AAA=0 then 'N' Else 'Y' End As AAA,
    Case when BBB=0 then 'N' Else 'Y' End as BBB,
    Case when CCC=0 then 'N' Else 'Y' End as CCC,
    AAA+BBB+CCC as TotalY
From tblClientInformation
```

If those three fields can have different values, we would be able to adjust to that as well.

**Update:** As per a comment from the OP, there *can* be values other than 0 or 1 for fields AAA, BBB, and CCC; that being the case, I have modified the query to have a nested query to achieve the same results without resorting to a CTE. Since we aren't doing anything recursive, the CTE will have no performance benefit here (I tested with 2.5M rows) and many people find a CTE to be harder to read... Here's the updated query:

```
SELECT 
    ClientName
    ,ClientNo
    ,AAA
    ,BBB
    ,CCC
    ,LEN(REPLACE(AAA+BBB+CCC, 'N',''))
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ClientName,
        ClientNo, 
        CASE WHEN AAA=0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS AAA,
        CASE WHEN BBB=0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS BBB,
        CASE WHEN CCC=0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS CCC
    FROM tblClientInformation
)a
```

Comment: The only way I see to do it is to basically count all 'Y' values since the values of the fields can vary depending on the field. However, for all of them, I'm doing a CASE WHEN ELSE statement, and my end result is always N or Y.

Answer (score 2):

You can compose a new query over your own with CTE:

```
;WITH table_without_count as
( Select ClientName, ClientNo, 
   Case when AAA=0 then 'N' Else 'Y' End As AAA,
   Case when BBB=0 then 'N' Else 'Y' End as BBB,
   Case when CCC=0 then 'N' Else 'Y' End as CCC
  From tblClientInformation
)
select *, LEN(REPLACE(AAA+BBB+..., 'N', '')) as TotalY
from table_without_count
```

Comment: A bit shorter version  `LEN(REPLACE(AAA+BBB+..., 'N', ''))`